# npm package installation failed while installing datatables in angular

Tags: angular, angular-datatables, npm-package

I am including datatables in my angular application. When I run

```
ng add angular-datatables
```

I get the following error code (please refer the image).
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm9EP.jpg)

I am not sure what is causing this error.
Please run through the package.json as well.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsdm9.jpg)

Comment: Please include the actual error, rather than a screenshot. Same applies for your code, share the code, not an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade karma to 5.2.+ as your angular devkit requires it. Also if you have code or errors please paste the text instead of an image.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Well I upgraded the angular version but angular material was not upgraded. It was still in version 8.0.3. Problem solved after upgrading angular material.

Apologies for not putting actual code. Shall take care of it next time.

Thanks a lot!